# OleDbEnumerator different behavior

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am running the following code in 2 different projects. Both the projects are built under .NET 4.5 framework in C# on the same machine. Entity reference framework is installed in both the projects and both projects are built for Debug X86 configuration.

```
 static bool AceOleDb15Present()
    {
        OleDbEnumerator enumerator = new OleDbEnumerator();
        DataTable table = enumerator.GetElements();
        bool bNameFound = false;
        bool bCLSIDFound = false;
        string flTempColVal;

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(flTempColVal = row[col].ToString());
                if ((col.ColumnName.Contains("SOURCES_NAME")) && (flTempColVal.Contains("Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0")))
                    bNameFound = true;
                if ((col.ColumnName.Contains("SOURCES_CLSID")) && (flTempColVal.Contains("{3BE786A0-0366-4F5C-9434-25CF162E475E}")))
                    bCLSIDFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (bNameFound && bCLSIDFound)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

One project reports the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 exits and other project does not report Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0.

Unable to find the difference/issue.

Comment: Do both projects (or rather the startup project builds) use the same processor target (build - platform target - 32 bit / 64 bit) ?

Comment: Both the projects are built for Debug x86 configuration